# Targetting a text element with no tag in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to target a date in `bs4` that has no tag associated with it.

The structure of the HTML is:

```
<div class="story-postdate">
  <div class="label-inline">Published</div>
  Feb 6, 2020, 4:40 pm SGT
</div>
```

I've tried `.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'story-postdate'})` and then tried to use the `sibling` selector. But no joy.

I've also tried to target it with `.text` at the end of the CSS selector. But that still returns a none object type.

Comment: What do you mean "no tag associated with it"? The text is a child of your first div.

Comment: I meant that no tag to target directly with an xpath or css selector.

Comment: Jquery solution accepted? (It's hard to solve this by vanilla JS, but very easy by jquery). Your issue related to CSS (Style "select" "Feb 6, 2020...") or selecting the text node by js? What is your end target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = """<div class="story-postdate">
  <div class="label-inline">Published</div>
  Feb 6, 2020, 4:40 pm SGT
</div>"""

# using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='lxml')
print (soup.find('div',attrs={'class' : 'story-postdate'}).div.next_sibling)

# using SimplifiedDoc
doc  = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.select('div.story-postdate>div').nextText())
```

Here are more examples of SimplifiedDoc Library: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = '''<div class="story-postdate">
  <div class="label-inline">Published</div>
  Feb 6, 2020, 4:40 pm SGT
</div>'''

b = soup(html, 'html.parser')
div_tag = b.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'story-postdate'})
for div in div_tag:
    print(" ".join(div.text.split()[1:]))
```

Output:

```
Feb 6, 2020, 4:40 pm SGT
```

Or :

```
print(" ".join(div.text.split()[1:4]))
```

Output:

```
Feb 6, 2020,
```